# How to work with async/await in vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vue-router

In vue router `beforeEach` I have code:

```
function foo() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        //load data from http request 
        resolve() 
    }) 
}

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => { 
    await foo()
    next()
}
```

The problem is only when I refresh the page or enter first time, `beforeach` is calling two times, I don't know why? How can I override this behaviour? I want to wait some data from API before user enters the page.

If there is no async await in `beforeEach` it works as expected.

Comment: try add url match condition like : `if(to.path=='/url_path') await foo()`